# Include GET variable on .htaccess link?

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, url

I have the following .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^register.html$ ?page=register
```

I have a jquery ajax function which requests the following normally, it works.

```
www.blabla.com/#!?page=register&module=ajax
```

However, it get's bugged when I use it with .htaccess

```
www.blabla.com/#!kayit.html&module=ajax [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 114 ms]
```

How can I solve this, any ideas?

Comment: Your RewriteRule matches neither request. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: How can I get it matched? $module=ajax is just a null thing to prevent ajax request from being loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't. You are using the fragment identifier (the text after the hash symbol) as a path (which normal procedure for ajax-y websites), but the fragment identifier never even reaches the server.
You have to make an ajax request to the server with the content of it.

The actual question would be, how to merge GET variables from the Rewrite Rule with the ones, already provided.

So in your example, you want the URL `register.html?var=1` to be redirected to `?page=register&var=1`. You can do that by adding the `qsappend` (query string append) flag:

```
RewriteRule ^register.html$ ?page=register [qsappend]
```

Docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags

Comment: A hashtag is a system to categorising things on Twitter. A hash symbol in a URI indicates the start of a fragment identifier.

Comment: This is correct. You simulate URLs in an ajax-y environment by writing and modifying the hash tag. But the hash tag is not actually sent to the server. You have to fetch the content of the hash tag, parse it in javascript, make an ajax request to the server with an actual URL and include the received contents in the page. But you cannot skip the part with "fetch the URL and do an ajax request" and expect it to work.

Comment: It worked. Is there anything I should be aware of when using qsappend?

Comment: Can you stop calling "fragment identifiers" "hash tags", those are something completely different.

Comment: @ Quentin: sorry, it's obviously to early in the morning here. I edited my answer. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Anıl Ünal yes. A provided GET parameter will override your parameter in the .htaccess file. So calling `register.html?page=index` will set `$_GET["page"] === "index"`.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `#` actually you commented line.

you can use [summyjs](http://sammyjs.org/) for ajax request like gmail.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-an-introduction-to-sammy-js/

Answer (score 0):

Fragment identifiers:

1. Are handled entirely client side and are never sent from the client to the server
2. Must appear at the **end** of the URI, **after** the query string